# Should I use any Ethereum Wallet listed on your search engine or advertisments?

Tags: discussion

Spoiler: **No!**

It comes up [once in a while](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17652/missing-eth-on-ethereum-wallet-info) that users wonder why their tokens are missing from their legit-looking wallet they found via search engine.

So here comes my warning: Don't use any Ethereum Wallet listed on Google!

It takes a dedicated scammer **15 minutes to setup a website** that allows him to steal your coins. And it takes him **another 15 bucks to set up Google ads** exactly matching the terms "Ethereum" and "Wallet".

Don't get caught. Use one of the known legit working wallets. I personally can recommend the following:

- [Mist Wallet](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/latest): [mist](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mist) [geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geth)[ethereum-wallet-dapp](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethereum-wallet-dapp)
- [Parity Wallet](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/releases/latest): [parity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parity) [parity-wallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parity-wallet)
- [Harmony Wallet](https://github.com/ether-camp/ethereum-harmony/releases/latest): [harmony](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harmony) [ethereumj](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethereumj)
- [MetaMask Chrome extension](https://metamask.io/): [metamask](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metamask)
- [MyEtherWallet](https://myetherwallet.com/): [myetherwallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myetherwallet) [cold-storage](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-storage)
- [Ledger Nano S](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/Ledger_Nano_S) or [Trezor](https://blog.trezor.io/trezor-integration-with-myetherwallet-3e217a652e08) hardware wallets: [ledger-nano-s](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ledger-nano-s) [trezor](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trezor) [hardware-wallets](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware-wallets)

There are some sites that are set up to have domains that look similar to the wallets above -- don't be fooled and stay safe!

Comment: what about ether.li, many question was about it?

Comment: IMO, this could go as a community wiki in the main site.

Comment: @BadrBellaj ether.li is only minimally maintained and I would not recommend using it because it keeps confusing users. It's a nice piece of technology though.

Comment: @5chdn no i meant we need to add an alerte to your post that many users are facing some problems with this wallet.