# 2017 Graduation Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we are holding a Q&A thread for the candidates. Questions collected [from an earlier thread](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/477/2017-graduation-moderator-election-qa-question-collection?cb=1) have been compiled into this one, which shall now serve as the space for the candidates to provide their answers.

We have selected all provided questions as well as two of our backup questions to come to 10 questions total.

As a candidate, your job is simple - post an answer to this question, citing each of the questions and then post your answer to each question given in that same answer. For your convenience, I will include all of the questions in quote format with a break in between each, suitable for you to insert your answers. Just [copy the whole thing after the first set of three dashes](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/6388852b-d02d-4a08-a858-7965ea0dcdc4/view-source).Please consider putting your name at the top of your post so that readers will know who you are before they finish reading everything you have written, and also including a link to your answer on your nomination post.

Once all the answers have been compiled, this will serve as a transcript for voters to view the thoughts of their candidates, and will be appropriately linked in the Election page.

Good luck to all of the candidates!

**Oh, and when you've completed your answer, please provide a link to it after this blurb here, before that set of three dashes. Please leave the list of links in the order of submission.**

To save scrolling here are links to the submissions from each candidate (in order of submission):

- [Bellaj's answers](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/a/499/2021)
- [Richard's answers](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/a/495/52)
- [@eth's answers](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/a/497/42)

---

> 1. What keeps you coming back to the Ethereum Stack Exchange? Things may be "hot" now, and what will keep you coming back when things "cool" down?
> 2. From [On Ethereum Classic usage](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/on-ethereum-classic-usage): "...Ethereum Classic questions will be well on topic..." Agree/disagree/ambivalent?
> 3. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
> 4. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?
> 5. Moderators can help improve the site and sometimes this can be "clean up". What areas/s, if any, are you motivated or nags you to improve or clean up?
> 6. Should we discourage questions about exchanges, trading, buying? ... How? :)
> 7. What strengths do you think you would bring to being a moderator? Which of your "weaknesses" do you think would make it more difficult for you to being moderator?
> 8. One of the very important things I would like to see with Eth SE would be to have a section for generic (and some targeted question) which will help new users and like currently, a discussion of PoS is going can be better structured. What do you think as a candidate on this?
> 9. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
> 10. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 12):

This post might be off-topic as I am not a candidate, but I would like to answer the last question publicly as some members of the community approached me about running for moderator.

> 10. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

That's exactly what I will do: reaching 20k rep. I already have enough reputation to access moderator tools and decided not to run for moderator spot in this election. I am more than pleased to see that we have at least 10 motivated candidates willing to keep this site running.

It was always my goal to promote and shape Ethereum Stack Exchange to enable a fast graduation. And here we are now! I probably need a break from flag-handling but will be around every day to answer questions, comment, vote, protect, and delete (or flag) like mad. :)

Happy elections and graduation everyone!

Answer (score 6):

it's @eth and nomination statement [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-19541).

> 1. What keeps you coming back to the Ethereum Stack Exchange? Things may be "hot" now, and what will keep you coming back when things "cool" down?

When this site launched on day 1, I joined because I thought this site should be a clean, reference site for the community: just like how stackoverflow has been very helpful to countless developers. **I will keep coming back to the site because there is always something to improve about it.**

For example, there are always questions that I think I could write a good answer to, and we should all remember that it is OK and maybe even better if questions have more than 1 answer. There's also many questions to edit/improve and site clean up.

> 2. From [On Ethereum Classic usage](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/on-ethereum-classic-usage): "...Ethereum Classic questions will be well on topic..." Agree/disagree/ambivalent?

Agree on-topic and tagging them ethereum-classic.

> 3. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

IMHO this case is more likely to happen on more subjective questions since there's little room for arguments/flags on objective questions. Now if a user provided a valuable answer and added extra opinions which generate the flags, **I would add a comment for the user to trim their answers and focus on objectivity**. A few such comments should hopefully help. If the user still persists on adding opinions, I might help improve the 2nd-best answer and upvote it.

While mods and high-rep users might be able to edit someone else's answer, I would probably avoid that confrontation. Unless there's other cases of "bad behavior", I think a user ban would be too heavy and there are **ways for the community to workaround the user's suboptimal behavior**.

> 4. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

Most of the time I would let it be: there's many things that time could be spent on improving the site. If it was a pattern where the other mod and I disagreed, I would try talking to them in the Ethereum mods chat room, listen to them, and present my opinion. If there is still heavy disagreement, consult other mods.

> 5. Moderators can help improve the site and sometimes this can be "clean up". What areas/s, if any, are you motivated or nags you to improve or clean up?

When I answer a question, usually I am "nagged" and also end up editing the question to improve its title and how the question is asked. (I hope the community does this more, and even improving the title of a question will help all the people who end up searching for it, and you may also be one of the searchers in the future.)

Tags because they are important for helping the Stack Exchange algorithm to identify related answers, and make it easier for people to learn about some topics too. For example, a recent clean up was separating out [thedao-refund](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thedao-refund) from [gas-refund](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gas-refund) so that people who want to learn about one don't have to get clutter about the other.

Duplicates or similar questions that always get asked. With some topics, like upgradable contracts, I really want to help the community have a "go to place" for those answers, instead of having to keep searching for them.

> 6. Should we discourage questions about exchanges, trading, buying? ... How? :)

Some questions about exchanges and how to buy are on-topic. Trading and buying/investment advice is off-topic so close such questions as off-topic. We can also refine https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

> 7. What strengths do you think you would bring to being a moderator? Which of your "weaknesses" do you think would make it more difficult for you to being moderator?

**Fairness and community focus**: mods should be as unbiased as possible IMHO. A solid knowledge about Ethereum and the community is also helpful: for example in recognising scams, answers that are accidentally inaccurate, or for tagging questions accurately and having tags that might be helpful. All mods don't need to have strong knowledge of Ethereum, but IMHO at least one should.

Time constraints are a "weakness", can't do everything, and sometimes I may spend too much time on writing a single answer: I care about providing very good answers to the community. I also always look at Meta, but don't have as much time to make many posts to it.

If I get voted as a mod, I hope that the whole team of (3) mods can complement each other well.

> 8. One of the very important things I would like to see with Eth SE would be to have a section for generic (and some targeted question) which will help new users and like currently, a discussion of PoS is going can be better structured. What do you think as a candidate on this?

Yes, definitely! @atomh33ls started [this](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/faq-frequently-asked-questions-and-reference-answers). I support such efforts but have not been able to focus on this due to time constraints as mentioned above.

> 9. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

Honestly, I did not notice the diamond. Because I've tried posting a lot of good answers on the site, I am very aware about the attention my answers and comments can have, so **I try to be very careful and accurate with what I post**. Sometimes when I see an answer that might have an inaccuracy, I might post an answer since I would like to help the community with a solid answer, and the intention is never to be a "bully". **I also think pretty much 100% of my posts have been respectful**.

> 10. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

I think there are some permissions, like merging questions, which might only be available to mods. So I can be more effective by being able to do those things, and while I sparingly merge questions, I have done so when I think it will really help the community: for example the question on upgradeable contracts is helpful so that people don't have to look in so many places and possibly miss different techniques. Being a mod can also help with Q8, with the potential editing, closing, merging that might need to be done.

Also, with @5chdn not running, I think I can be of some/little help to fellow mods from my experience of being a mod pro tempore.

Comment: remark : I think the link you are using under your nomination(nomination statement here.) will not take the visitors to your nomination post while the posts are displayed randomly.

Comment: @BadrBellaj Thank you.  I copied the idea from RichardHorrocks and will let him know too that it doesn't look like it works anymore.  I don't have a better idea so will just leave it.

Comment: the ideal would be to add the Q/A link to the nomination post. I've tried but apparently we could not edit the nomination post

Comment: Thanks for letting me know guys :-)

Answer (score 5):

My name's Richard, and you can find my nomination statement [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-20808). Apologies if the below is a little long!

---

> 1. What keeps you coming back to the Ethereum Stack Exchange? Things may
>      be "hot" now, and what will keep you coming back when things "cool"
>      down?

I've been a member of the board since day one, and backed it during the [Area51 phase](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89704/ethereum). Blockchain isn't going away, and it's going to be hot for a long while yet. Bitcoin has been around since 2009, and in my opinion, Ethereum has introduced a layer of utility that far surpasses what Bitcoin currently has to offer. We've only just begun to scratch the surface.

The things that specifically keep me coming back, are:

- **The community**

Ethereum's technology stack can be overbearing, and it can be scary, especially for newcomers. It would be easy for this community to treat the proverbial "dumb question" from newcomers with condescension and redicule, but instead it treats them with tolerance and understanding. A lot of us have been in the same boat.

So it *genuinely* feels like a community, and I enjoy being part of it.

- **Learning and solving problems**

Ethereum is inherently *interesting*. It *makes* you want to learn about it. The technology is developing at a rapid rate, which means there's always more to learn and understand. The complexity of the technology stack also lends itself to complex problems, which I enjoy solving. (Or at least trying to!)

- **Helping people**

My primary reason for joining Ethreum Stack Exchange was so I could learn from all the people who knew what they were talking about. I learned a lot, and *I still do*. But my focus has changed, and I now spend most of my time putting back into the community by answering questions and helping others. This gives me a big sense of satisfaction and enjoyment.

---

> 2. From On Ethereum Classic usage
>
> ...Ethereum Classic questions will be well on topic...
>   Agree/disagree/ambivalent?

It's difficult to answer this without falling either side of the partisan ETH-ETC line, which I don't want to do!

In short: **I agree.**

It would be a shame if the board couldn't extend its support to everyone, especially newcomers, regardless of which side of the line they stand. A slight difference in opinion shouldn't lead to one party being blocked from an invaluable source of support.

In an ideal world, people would leave their politics at the door, and just give each other a hand with all this difficult stuff. Ideals are always hard to reach, but we can at least try to get as close as possible by extending a welcome to everybody.

---

> 3. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of
>      arguments/flags from comments?

For me, one of the most important aspects of the community is the *feel*. It should feel like the sort of place where people want to spend time. Where they can learn without fear of being ridiculed for asking dumb questions. People in groups don't always agree - that's unavoidable. But there should be a level of decorum and mutual respect that people *try* to adhere to.

Good answers are great, and contribute to the health of the site, but if the price is the gradual erosion of the feel of the community, then that needs to be fixed. To do so would require a procedure:

- Talk to the user to ensure they understand what effect their behaviour is having on other users. Perhaps they're blissfully unaware that they're causing offence!
- During this initial talk I'd make a request for them to self-moderate.
- If this fell on deaf ears, and there were further reports, then I'd consider a temporary ban.
  (Note: I don't currently know the procedure for the use of bans. It's something I'd have to learn about, which itself is part of the fun of taking on a moderator role!)

Finally, with something as serious as a ban, I'd ensure to get second or third opinions from other moderators to be sure of my own judgement

---

> 4. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

I'd *talk* to them :-)

Stack Exchange is about communication. Users communicate ideas in the form of Q+As and comments, and more subtly using up and down votes. The moderator community shouldn't be any different. The moderators have to work together to ensure their *own* community functions effectively. On the main site, when someone posts a question, and it isn't clear what they're asking, you leave a comment asking them to clarify. The situation outlined here would be no different.

I'd talk to them and try to understand the reasons for their actions and decisions. Most importantly, I'd remain open to being in the wrong! If this still results in an impasse, I'd ask for opinions from the other moderators.

---

> 5. Moderators can help improve the site and sometimes this can be "clean up". What areas/s, if any, are you motivated or nags you to
>      improve or clean up?

Firstly, the current moderators have done an superb job, and watching them has been one of the motivations for wanting to get my hands dirty(-er). Not because I think I can do better, but because it would be a privilege to carry on their work.

However, I have some ideas...

- **As a priority, decide what is exactly on- and off-topic.**
  There are several ongoing Meta threads concerning this (e.g. [mining](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/487/at-what-point-are-mining-questions-off-topic), [trading](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/470/should-we-discourage-questions-about-exchanges-trading-buying)). The sooner an agreement is reached, the sooner the community knows what it should and shouldn't be flagging. A little work now will save more work further down the line.
- **Remove stale and dead questions.**
  These *might* include:

  - Questions that have been answered in the comments under the main question.
  - Questions that apply to previous versions of software that are no longer relevant. (e.g. Old versions of Geth.)
  - Questions that are VLQ (very low quality) and have neither been voted up nor down.
- **Mark accepted answers.**
  There are lots of questions that are answered, even to the point where the OP has commented "Thanks!", but which aren't accepted as answered.
- **Migrate where possible.**
  Again something that has [come up in Meta](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/486/why-do-some-people-asking-about-ethereum-in-stackoverflow-instead-es). We need to formulate a strategy to consolidate Ethereum-related questions across all SE boards.
- **Follow ups.**
  Lots of questions stall at the first hurdle and require more information to be provided before anyone can answer them. In such cases users often comment for further information, but things don't move any further. For these questions I would propose following up further, and closing or putting on hold if no response is forthcoming.
- **Weekly or fortnightly digests.**
  At times of high traffic it's easy for good questions to not get the attention they deserve. Even if they're upvoted, they can get lost in a sea of questions about slow Mist syncs and missing ETH...

But... these are the things that take time, and I imagine a moderator's job is hectic enough. The challenge is to find the time to prioritise these things effectively, or empower other members of community enough that they see the value in doing it, and take on the responsibility.

---

> 6. Should we discourage questions about exchanges, trading, buying?

Sometimes these questions are easy: they're speculative, so you flag them as opinion-based. For example, "Which is the best exchange?" would generate lots of conflicting opinionated answers.

But we also get lots of questions from users - often the more inexperienced ones - who are panicking because they think they might have lost money. In these cases it would be cruel to show them no support whatsoever.

I like the idea of a **community wiki answer**, perhaps on the Meta site, that is kept up to date with some basic details or advice in different scenarios. We have [a similar post for wallets](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/should-i-use-any-ethereum-wallet-listed-on-your-search-engine-or-advertisments).

For example, the post could explain who to contact in cases of missing transactions between exchanges - i.e. contact the exchange directly. Or it could link to other SE sites or Reddit boards - e.g. reddit.com/r/ethtrader.

Once these posts were in place, any future questions on the topic could be closed (as off-topic), but with a pointer to the advice page/post.

---

> 7. What strengths do you think you would bring to being a moderator? Which of your "weaknesses" do you think would make it more difficult
>      for you to being moderator?

Firstly, I like to think that I'm fair and respectful, even to people whose opinions I disagree with. I like to think I'm patient and understanding of people's abilities and needs.

I believe I'm a good communicator, who is able to make complicated ideas and explanations clear and understandable. Believe it or not I used to be an English teacher... which also required good management and organisational skills, both similarly important in a moderator role.

I like the board to be clean. I like to think that everything has its rightful place, and I feel that the SE interface and procedures allow people to do that to a fairly comprehensive degree.

On the weaknesses side, one thing I've noticed I've done on various occasions is that I haven't taken ownership of something I've started. I like the idea of *"if you touch it, you own it"*, meaning that if you start down the path of answering something, you should conclude it to the best of your ability. There are a couple of cases where I've engaged with the user who asked a question - perhaps by asking for more information in the comments - but then didn't follow up further. This is something I can improve on.

---

> 8. One of the very important things I would like to see with Eth SE would be to have a section for generic (and some targeted question)
>      which will help new users and like currently, a discussion of PoS is
>      going can be better structured. What do you think as a candidate on
>      this?

My opinion on this would be similar to the ideas in question 6.

We could perhaps have Meta posts for certain topics that are shown in the *"Featured on Meta"* section of the main board (on the right-hand side). These could contain links to already-answered questions on the topics, or links to external, trusted sites. (For example, the [official Ethereum blog](https://blog.ethereum.org/), or other such sources of authority.)

We would need to be careful that these didn't become free-form *discussions* though. Discussions tend to lead to different people expressing different opinions - we would need to make sure the line between objectivity and subjectivity isn't crossed.

This would be something for the wider community to discuss.

---

> 9. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you
>      will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about
>      that?

For better or worse, when I initially joined Stack Exchange I joined using my real name. My profile picture is really me. (Although that picture is 2 years old and I've eaten a lot of saturated fat since then... ) As such, anything posted in the past can be traced to my real identity. I've tried to behave as I do in person, when I'm face-to-face with real people. Having a diamond next to my real name will only strengthen the way I feel about treating other users with respect and fairness.

---

> 10. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Moderation isn't just about rep. If your rep increases as a by-product of your duties, then that's great. But moderation also involves lots of tasks that don't come with an associated rep reward. The sometimes menial tasks that are required to keep the site running smoothly, and the cases where a moderator is required to step in to settle a dispute. It is *these* things that will make me more effective as a moderator, rather than just chasing reputation earnings.

Comment: FYI @BaddrBellaj commented on mine: "I think the link you are using under your nomination(nomination statement here.) will not take the visitors to your nomination post while the posts are displayed randomly."  (Just letting you know; I do not have a better idea so just leaving it as is.)

Comment: Ah, yes, that's annoying :-) I think I'll leave mine as is too - at least it gets them to the voting page... Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 5):

My name is **[Bellaj badr](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/election/)** 
I am providing short answers to give you an idea about my vision, if you need further clarifications,please comment below:

> 1. What keeps you coming back to the Ethereum Stack Exchange? Things may be "hot" now, and what will keep you coming back when things "cool" down?

I have three main reasons:

- **I learn from ESE (Ethereum Stack Exchange)**: the posted questions help me to test my technical knowledge, to perform it and to discover new things.
- **I want to help the others**: I claim that I have an open source collaborative mentality, I like helping people to resolve their problems and to move forward. During my career, other people helped me and now it’s my turn to pay back my duties.
- **I really care for this community**: I'd like to help make ESE a primary source of helpful answers for everybody.

> 2. From [On Ethereum Classic usage](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/on-ethereum-classic-usage): "...Ethereum Classic questions will be well on topic..." Agree/disagree/ambivalent?

Ethereum classic is an Ethereum after all, in my opinion we should accept the questions about it as on-topic questions.

> 3. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

I think it’s good for ESE to have such users who provide valuable answers.  Unless the user provides rude or off-topic comments, I’ll ask him by chat or comment to reassemble all the arguments he is providing and formulate a complete answer.  Otherwise, I will delete the comments or move the discussion to chat.
If the situation persists, I'd probably consult with the other moderators to try to find a solution in accordance with the ESE policies.

> 4. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

I believe the future moderators are (as was the previous ones) professional and high qualified people, so such matters could be easily handled by a reasonable discussion. I’ll try to understand his reasons and try to **reach a consensus** maybe by proposing a question edition or I’ll try to convince him in a dedicated chat.

> 5. Moderators can help improve the site and sometimes this can be "clean up". What areas/s, if any, are you motivated or nags you to improve or clean up?

I’ve been already helping cleaning up the site, but I think I would help more in:

- Redefining old tags.
- editing old answers/questions.
- Replacing old links
- Clarifying bad questions
- Looking for duplicated questions

> 6. Should we discourage questions about exchanges, trading, buying? ... How? :)

In general, **we shouldn’t discourage** such questions, but it depends on the question.
I think a question like [“where to buy Ethereum”](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1915/how-do-i-buy-ethereum-with-usd) is a legitimate question and we should provide the needed answers. You may remark that this question has been visited `204940 times`. I think these subjects generate a limited space of questions and they tend to be duplicated, so we need first to answer them and then flag the new ones as duplicated.
However, **I think we should discourage** obsolete questions depending on a specific service provider which didn’t have any technical need or added value like “I haven’t received my money on X platform.” we don’t want ESE to become a help desk for these services.

> 7. What strengths do you think you would bring to being a moderator? Which of your "weaknesses" do you think would make it more difficult for you to being moderator?

**Strengths** :

- I have the ability to manage (as I do in my work) with a gentle
  touch (most of time) and with a firm hand when it’s needed to preserve
  the site quality and to prevent spammers from abusing the platform.
- I am an active Listener, knowledgeable and dedicated person to help,
  I have a high energy level which will helps me to fulfill my duties as
  a moderator even in pressure situations.
- I have the ability to operate effectively in a team (mod team).
- The [Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) considers Moderators as **human exception
  handlers**, I believe that I have the needed patience and a good
  understanding of human nature to catch those exceptions.

**Weakness** :

- I love chocolate :p (JK).
- I have never been a moderator on ESE before but it’s time for me to
  serve the community.
- I am a mistake Making Human but I have the courage to admit my
  mistakes and to correct them.

> 8. One of the very important things I would like to see with Eth SE would be to have a section for generic (and some targeted question) which will help new users and like currently, a discussion of PoS is going can be better structured. What do you think as a candidate on this?

There is already a complete [FAQ](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/faq-frequently-asked-questions-and-reference-answers/435#435) (Frequently Asked Questions and Reference Answers) section in the meta forum. I think as a moderator I will improve this section content and use it to guide the new users.

> 9. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

I understand that a moderator has a reputation to preserve while the other users are perceiving him as a model and trustworthy person. Before running for the moderation election, I was always very careful about my answers and I tried to provide valuable interventions and answers which will help people maybe for years (I test my code, I check the official documentation, editing old answers, etc…).
I believe becoming a moderator will make me feel a big responsibility and make me more vigilant because I have to show the right example to the community about the usage of the site.

> 10. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Unlike being a highly reputed user, **being a moderator is a responsibility and an engagement**. therefore, **I will feel more involved** and I’ll allocate more time to fulfill my duties and to work harder in order to remain loyal to my election promises.
Moreover, there is a respect for the moderators in the SE communities and therefore their voice is more audible than the others, this fact would help me to easily communicate with the users and to enhance the ESE performance. Besides, I think the moderator abilities allow me to boost the ESE activity and to make it a valuable source of information and help.

Answer (score -3):

---

> 1. What keeps you coming back to the Ethereum Stack Exchange? Things may be "hot" now, and what will keep you coming back when things "cool" down?

I am mostly here to edit new comers questions as well as answers, because years of being here and other SE sites shown me that most of the questions are probably answered so I can close them or edit for better understanding for future visitors.

> 2. From [On Ethereum Classic usage](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/on-ethereum-classic-usage): "...Ethereum Classic questions will be well on topic..." Agree/disagree/ambivalent?

Absolutely no need, they use the same source anyway. We can deal with it with a simple Tag.

> 3. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

Would like to educate them by providing link to faq and meta article.

> 4. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

I'd write a comment on most cases, or I'd edit and resubmit for reopen.

> 5. Moderators can help improve the site and sometimes this can be "clean up". What areas/s, if any, are you motivated or nags you to improve or clean up?

I am concerned about the content formatting and duplicate questions. And yes, sometimes I struggled to find previous questions I saw here.

> 6. Should we discourage questions about exchanges, trading, buying? ... How? :)

We should create it as an option in closing reasons popup. Because this is mostly a technology community and might not be interested in the finance aspects, and there are better places for chatty questions like Reddit.

> 7. What strengths do you think you would bring to being a moderator? Which of your "weaknesses" do you think would make it more difficult for you to being moderator?

I got plenty of time, and I believe I am familiar with the site functions and the possibilities here as a moderator.

> 8. One of the very important things I would like to see with Eth SE would be to have a section for generic (and some targeted question) which will help new users and like currently, a discussion of PoS is going can be better structured. What do you think as a candidate on this?

Personally, I dont think we need it. Because most of the core devs are more active in Reddit than Eth SE. And what we can summarise here by providing such a platform is just random thoughts from people with no in-depth knowledge of the platform or the Blockchain itself. This is more like a developer (Like using the API) space.

> 9. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

I'd call it fancy. We have whats enough to run the ecosystem.

> 10. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Its not really about reputation for me? Most of the time ill be formatting the questions which will not earn me reputation,